# PHP, SQL Сортировка изображений по индексу

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте!

Есть проблема. Нужно в административной панели реализовать функционал, так чтобы я мог загружать большое количество изображений и мог менять порядок их вывода, допустим, хочу чтобы второе изображение стало первым и так далее. Это очень удобно!

Подскажите пожалуйста, может уже есть готовые решение. Очень нужно, а как это сделать понятия не имею...

Comment: добавьте поле с порядком в БД изображений и давайте через админку его менять

Comment: а как то более раскрыто можно объяснить?

Comment: Поясните как будет лучше, нужно загружать все изображения в одну колонку в базе и выводить её циклом или как?

Comment: Во первых держать картинки в БД все таки не стоит. в БД кладете только пути где они лежат. И структура БД должна быть 1 картинка - 1 запись и у этой записи есть поле с порядком вывода